# Lightbox display multiple images from directory

Tags: php, html, css, image, lightbox

I can not find an answer(that works) to this anywhere on the web.

I am trying to get Lightbox to load images from a directory as they will be frequently updated.

If anyone can correct what I'm doing wrong, or has a solution using either PHP or a hidden div populated automatically by a specific directory it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have come up with but is not seeming to work;

```
<?php $dirname = "img/love/"; $images = glob($dirname."*.jpg"); foreach($images as $image) { echo '<img data-lightbox="love" src="'.$image.'" /><br />'; } ?>
```

and here is my test page: http://knowledgeoverfame.com/tslp/leet/alt/index.html

I didn't find any similar questions here with an answer to this but if i may have missed it please enlighten me :)

Thanks!

Comment: please elaborate more...what are you trying to do...

Comment: I have a code for this. If it hasnt been answered by the time i get to a computer i will post it.

Comment: Try using double quotes for the echo

Comment: trying to get Lightbox to pull images from a directory on my server instead of having to link to each image individually

Comment: Thanks Josan, I tried the double quotes and it didn't work :/

Comment: Is your issue not getting any images or displaying of multiple images?

Comment: im not getting anything arunrc, I just want the Lightbox to pull an image from the directory, display it, and allow the user to cycle through each image in the directory one by one. Hope that makes sense haha

Comment: Have you tried using `scandir()` to get an array of the image files?...

Comment: @jacelysh no I haven't, I'm not super familiar with php, could you give me an example as to how/where I would add this to what I have or use it? Thanks!

Comment: Please refer to my answer below..

Comment: Can you explain briefly that what you want or you want all the pictures are display on the page and user clicks on one picture and go through all the images Or you want that a picture is display like a album and user clicks on single image and all the images in that album

Comment: @ShaheerAli I have 3 thumbnail links to different image galleries which are frequently being updated, I want the user to be able to click on a thumbnail and have a Lightbox window open allowing the user to cycle through the selected image directory picture by picture. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `scandir()` to get an array of your image files.

Example:

```
<?php
  $images = scandir($your_folder);
  foreach ( $images as $key => $filename ) {
    if ( $key > 1 ) {  //ignores the first two values which refer to the current and parent directory
     echo '<img data-lightbox="love" src="'.$your_folder."/".$filename.'" /><br />';
   }    
  } 
?>
```

for reference: [PHP scandir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)

Comment: So would I add this to what I already have, or would this take the place of my current code?

Comment: I got it working, had to edit a tiny bit but thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do - use lightbox to display images from a folder - is a problem which has been solved lots of times with varying degrees of complexity. If you do a google search for something like "php image gallery" you will find sample scripts. I did just this about a year ago and after some experimentation I chose Minigal Nano as it was a powerful script but simple enough for it to be quite easy to see how it worked and then rework for my own use. I also found this an effective way to learn php.

Answer (score 0):

This script will pull the images from a directory. I used it with fancybox but you can modify to fit your needs.

```
<?php
$directory = 'yourDirectory/gallery/thumbs';   //where the gallery thumbnail images are located    
$files = glob($directory."/*.{jpg,jpeg,gif,png}", GLOB_BRACE);
natsort($files); //sort by filename
?>

<?php
for($x = 0; $x < count($files); $x++){
$thumb = $files[$x];
$file = basename($thumb);
$nomargin = $x%4 == 0?" nomargin":"";
$title = htmlspecialchars($file);
?>
    <div class="thumbs fancybox<?= $nomargin ?>" style="background:url('<?= $thumb ?>') no-repeat 50% 50%;">
        <a rel="group" href="yourDirectory/gallery/<?= $file ?>"></a> 
    </div>
<?php
}//end for loop
?>
```

Comment: Here is what I came up with and it seems to be doing the trick...

<?php
            $dirname = "img/love";
            $images = scandir("./img/love/");
                foreach ( $images as $key => $filename ) {
                    if ( $key > 1 ) {  //ignores the first two values which refer to the current and parent directory
                        echo '<a href="'.$dirname."/".$filename.'" data-lightbox="love"><div id="thumb"><img src="'.$dirname."/".$filename.'" height="150px" /></div></a>';
                    }    
                } 
            ?>

Comment: This was thanks to @Jacelysh with a little tweaking... do you foresee any problems with this? I'm curious, I'm not very fluent in PHP so I kinda just fudged with it until it worked haha

You can check http://knowledgeoverfame.com/tslp/leet/alt and click the Love link to see it in action...