# Lightbox display multiple images from specific directory

Tags: php, lightbox

I'm not sure that I asked the question in the right way, but I'm the first time here. At the following link, I found the answer to the problem I have.  [Lightbox display multiple images from directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25540534/lightbox-display-multiple-images-from-directory)
But, I am a complete novice, and when I put this php file and try to open it I get only a blank page. Does someone can help me find the mistake? What values should replace in the file?

Thank You!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lightbox display multiple images from directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25540534/lightbox-display-multiple-images-from-directory)

Comment: Are you see that link and try to check that marked answer at your end?